# Why is a finitely sheeted covering space of $\mathbb{R}^n$ never compact?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, covering-spaces

It is common to see the following consequence of Cartan-Hadamard stated as a significant result relating curvature and topology:

> Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with non-positive sectional curvature $K \leq 0$. Then the fundamental group of $M$ is infinite.

A common proof is using the Cartan-Hadamard theorem to guarantee that $M$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and concluding by stating without proof that a finite quotient of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is  never compact. I have seen a proof of this consequence using geometrical means (a compact group acting on $M$ by isometries has a fixed point), but I would really like to see a purely topological proof.

Comment: A finite cover of a compact space is compact.

Comment: @Deane thanks a lot! It has been so long since I've studied covering spaces that I had forgotten that fact. That settles it.

Comment: It's a bit more general: if you have a fiber bundle with compact typical fiber, the total space is compact if and only if the base of the bundle is compact. Throw in "finite spaces are compact" and "covering maps are fiber bundles with discrete fibers" and there you have it.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade You should write an answer to your own question.

Comment: @IvoTerek I didn't know that, that's cool! Thanks.

Comment: @PaulFrost I have just done so :)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Deane and Ivo for showing me the way! This answer is based on their comments.

Let $\widetilde{M}$ be the universal cover of $M$. We know that $M =\dfrac{ \widetilde{M}}{\pi_1(M)}$. If $\pi_1(M)$ was finite, then $\widetilde{M}$ would be compact as well (because anytime we have a finitely sheeted covering map $p: X \to Y$ with $Y$ compact, $X$ is compact too - for a proof of this, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159166/finitely-sheeted-covering-space-of-a-compact-space-is-compact) question or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072002/how-do-i-prove-that-a-finite-covering-space-of-a-compact-space-is-compact) one), but since $\widetilde{M}$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is noncompact, so $\pi_1(M)$ cannot be finite.

Alternatively, any covering map $p: \widetilde{M} \to M$ is a fiber bundle over $M$ (with fibers $\{p^{-1}(q) \}_{q \in M}$) with discrete fibers (as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006242/why-is-a-covering-map-a-fibre-bundle) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133519/covering-space-is-a-fiber-bundle)). If $\pi_1(M)$ is finite, then these fibers are not only discrete but finite (and all of them have the same cardinality, namely $|\pi_1(M) |$) and therefore compact. Now, since the total space (in this case, $\widetilde{M}$) of a fiber bundle with a compact base (in this case, $M$) and compact fibers (in this case, $\{ p^{-1}(q)\}_{q \in M}$) is compact, the finiteness of $\pi_1(M)$ would again imply the compactness of $\widetilde{M}$ (this is a consequence of a more general fact - the total space of a fiber bundle is compact if and only if both its base and fibers are compact, as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323711/fiber-bundle-is-compact-if-base-and-fiber-are) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4006624/compactness-about-fiber-bundle)), which we know cannot happen because $\widetilde{M}$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Hence $\pi_1(M)$ cannot be finite.

One can note that these arguments generalize a bit further: any compact manifold with noncompact universal cover has an infinite fundamental group (so, for example, $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^1$ also has an infinite fundamental group, even though it satisfies $K \geq 0$ - although explicitly computing its fundamental group is trivial even without geometry).

**UPDATE**: For the more general case where the quotient is not a covering space, one can take a look at [this blog post](https://amathew.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/negative-curvature-and-fundamental-groups/).

Comment: This solves a certain case of the question you posed, but what if the quotient $\Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^n/G$ is not a covering map? For instance, what about when you quotient $\Bbb{R}^2$ by $\Bbb{Z}/k\Bbb{Z}$ acting as roots of unity in $S^1$? You can probably upgrade your proof to this case by proving that points with trivial stabilizer are open and then running your argument or something like that...

Comment: @AlekosRobotis you are correct, thanks for pointing it out. I failed to appropriately title my question, the only case I had in mind were the ones where the quotient is a covering space. I'll change the title. I think [this blog post](https://amathew.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/negative-curvature-and-fundamental-groups/) appropriately answer the general question, though, and so I'll link it in my answer as well.